# Containers with the same height are not aligned from top

Tags: html, css, sass

I want to be able to have containers with the same height- without setting the fix height - even when their content text is not the same amount. As you can see on the codepen link the containers don't have the same height and are not aligned from the top. Basically the behavior I want to achieve is to have all containers with the same height (equal to the height of the container with maximum height) so containers must be aligned from top and bottom.

```
.info-block-tile-table{
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  width: 100%;
}

.info-block-tile-row{
  display: table-row;
}

.info-block-tile-cell{
  width: 25%;
  display: table-cell;
  float: none;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.info-block-tile {
  border-top: 5px solid #69be28;
  border-right: 1px solid #dfe1e4;
  border-left: 1px solid #dfe1e4;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dfe1e4;
  float: left;
  padding: 0.5rem
}




<div>

  <div class="info-block-tile-table">
    <div class="info-block-tile-row">
      <div class="info-block-tile-cell">
        <div class="info-block-tile">

          <h6 class="margin-top__0 margin-bottom__2 fiord font-weight-sourcesans__bold">Offering 1</h6>
          <p class="margin-top__0 margin-bottom__2 fiord font-weight-sourcesans__normal font-size__7">Lorem ipsum dolor
            sit amet, ius fastidii similique argumentum in, porro putent consetetur vix ut. Tibique percipitur ex vim,
            vim id idque soleat tibique, has te erant doctus complectitur. Nusquam oportere vituperata id cum, adipisci
            persecuti an pro. Eu vim facer graecis, id nec dicta integre interpretaris</p>


          <a href="http://www.google.com"
             class="aligned-bottom text-decoration__none rounded__thick corporateGreen white__hover background-corporateGreen__hover border border-width__2 font-size__6 padding-topbottom__1 margin-top__4 padding-leftright__4 position-float__left"
             target="_blank">
            <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
            Learn More
          </a>
        </div>


      </div>

      <div class="info-block-tile-cell">
        <div class="info-block-tile">

          <h6 class="margin-top__0 margin-bottom__2 fiord font-weight-sourcesans__bold">Offering 1</h6>
          <p class="margin-top__0 margin-bottom__2 fiord font-weight-sourcesans__normal font-size__7">Lorem ipsum dolor
            sit amet, ius fastidii similique argumentum in, porro putent consetetur vix ut. Tibique </p>


          <a href="http://www.google.com"
             class="aligned-bottom text-decoration__none rounded__thick corporateGreen white__hover background-corporateGreen__hover border border-width__2 font-size__6 padding-topbottom__1 margin-top__4 padding-leftright__4 position-float__left"
             target="_blank">
            <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
            Learn More
          </a>
        </div>


      </div>

      <div class="info-block-tile-cell">
        <div class="info-block-tile">

          <h6 class="margin-top__0 margin-bottom__2 fiord font-weight-sourcesans__bold">Offering 1</h6>
          <p class="margin-top__0 margin-bottom__2 fiord font-weight-sourcesans__normal font-size__7">Lorem ipsum dolor
            sit amet, ius fastidii similique argumentum in, porro putent consetetur vix ut. Tibique percipitur ex vim,
            vim id idque soleat tibique, has te erant doctus complectitur. Nusquam oportere vituperata id cum, adipisci
            persecuti an pro. Eu vim facer graecis, id nec dicta integre interpretaris</p>


          <a href="http://www.google.com"
             class="aligned-bottom text-decoration__none rounded__thick corporateGreen white__hover background-corporateGreen__hover border border-width__2 font-size__6 padding-topbottom__1 margin-top__4 padding-leftright__4 position-float__left"
             target="_blank">
            <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
            Learn More
          </a>
        </div>


      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="info-block-tile-row">
      <div class="info-block-tile-cell">
        <div class="info-block-tile">

          <h6 class="margin-top__0 margin-bottom__2 fiord font-weight-sourcesans__bold">Offering 1</h6>
          <p class="margin-top__0 margin-bottom__2 fiord font-weight-sourcesans__normal font-size__7">Lorem ipsum dolor
            sit amet, ius fastidii similique argumentum in, porro putent consetetur vix ut. T
          </p>


          <a href="http://www.google.com"
             class="aligned-bottom text-decoration__none rounded__thick corporateGreen white__hover background-corporateGreen__hover border border-width__2 font-size__6 padding-topbottom__1 margin-top__4 padding-leftright__4 position-float__left"
             target="_blank">
            <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
            Learn More
          </a>
        </div>


      </div>

      <div class="info-block-tile-cell">
        <div class="info-block-tile">

          <h6 class="margin-top__0 margin-bottom__2 fiord font-weight-sourcesans__bold">Offering 1</h6>
          <p class="margin-top__0 margin-bottom__2 fiord font-weight-sourcesans__normal font-size__7">Lorem ipsum dolor
            sit amet, ius fastidii similique argumentum in, porro putent consetetur vix ut. Tibique percipitur ex vim,
            vim id idque soleat tibique, has te erant doctus complectitur. Nusquam oportere vituperata id cum, adipisci
            persecuti an pro. Eu vim facer graecis, id nec dicta integre interpretaris</p>


          <a href="http://www.google.com"
             class="aligned-bottom text-decoration__none rounded__thick corporateGreen white__hover background-corporateGreen__hover border border-width__2 font-size__6 padding-topbottom__1 margin-top__4 padding-leftright__4 position-float__left"
             target="_blank">
            <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
            Learn More
          </a>
        </div>


      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

codepen link:  http://codepen.io/neginbasiri/pen/wWvjba

Comment: What is the behaviour you want? The containers are bottom aligned and can't be the same size unless you set fixed height and scrolling. Do you want it top-aligned and scrolling with fixed height?

Comment: I updated description. Containers must be aligned from top and bottom with the same height

Answer (score 0):

To `align-top` for a block, you can use:

```
.info-block-tile-cell {
  // Your code
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

And full height for container in `table-cell`, add more code:

```
.info-block-tile-table,
.info-block-tile {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: containers must be aligned from top and bottom - which means must have same height

Answer (score 0):

Changing the `CSS` class `.info-block-tile-cell` will let you top align it as follows:

```
.info-block-tile-cell{
  width: 25%;
  display: table-cell;
  float: none;
  padding: 1rem;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

You can make the tiles a fixed height with scroll bars as follows:

```
.info-block-tile {
    border-top: 5px solid #69be28;
    border-right: 1px solid #dfe1e4;
    border-left: 1px solid #dfe1e4;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dfe1e4;
    float: left;
    padding: 0.5rem;
    height:100%;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

Comment: Still doesn't have the same height. it must be aligned from top and bottom

Comment: For the same height, you need to set a `height` and `overflow` mode in `.info-block-tile`. I've edited the answer to show this. It's not possible to align from top and bottom. Do you mean to align it to the middle of the paragraph.

Comment: I know it is possible. I did it previously but not sure why this time doesn't work.

Comment: What is possible? I'm having trouble understanding what you mean by align from top and bottom. Once you add the above code to the fiddle, they'll have the same height and will be top aligned. Once you make the above changes to your fiddle, what further changes do you want done, visually?

Answer (score 0):

Use this it wil work..:)

```
.info-block-tile-table,
.info-block-tile {
  height: 100%;
verticle-align:top;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I resolved it. Here is the link to solution for reference.

http://codepen.io/neginbasiri/pen/wWvjba

```
<div class="info-block-tile-table">
  <div class="info-block-tile-row">
    <div class="info-block-tile-cell">
      <div class="info-block-tile">

        <h6 class="margin-top__0 margin-bottom__2 fiord font-weight-sourcesans__bold">Offering 1</h6>
        <p class="margin-top__0 margin-bottom__10 fiord font-weight-sourcesans__normal font-size__7">Lorem ipsum dolor sit
          amet, ius fastidii similique argumentum in, porro putent consetetur vix ut. Tibique percipitur ex vim, vim id
          idque soleat tibique, has te erant doctus complectitur. Nusquam oportere vituperata id cum, adipisci persecuti an
          pro. Eu vim facer graecis, id nec dicta integre interpretaris</p>

        <div class="tile-button-container">
          <a href="http://www.google.com" class="text-decoration__none rounded__thick corporateGreen white__hover background-corporateGreen__hover border border-width__2 font-size__6 padding-topbottom__1 padding-leftright__4 margin-bottom__4 position-float__left" target="_blank">
            <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
            Learn More
          </a>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>




    <div class="info-block-tile-cell">
      <div class="info-block-tile">

        <h6 class="margin-top__0 margin-bottom__2 fiord font-weight-sourcesans__bold">Offering 1</h6>
        <p class="margin-top__0 margin-bottom__10 fiord font-weight-sourcesans__normal font-size__7">Lorem ipsum dolor sit
          amet, ias te erant doctus complectitur. Nusquam oportere vituperata id cum, adipisci persecuti an
          pro. Eu vim facer graecis, id nec dicta integre interpretaris</p>

        <div class="tile-button-container">
          <a href="http://www.google.com" class="text-decoration__none rounded__thick corporateGreen white__hover background-corporateGreen__hover border border-width__2 font-size__6 padding-topbottom__1 padding-leftright__4 margin-bottom__4 position-float__left" target="_blank">
            <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
            Learn More
          </a>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>




    <div class="info-block-tile-cell">
      <div class="info-block-tile">

        <h6 class="margin-top__0 margin-bottom__2 fiord font-weight-sourcesans__bold">Offering 1</h6>
        <p class="margin-top__0 margin-bottom__10 fiord font-weight-sourcesans__normal font-size__7">Lorem ipsum dolor sit
          amet, ius fastidii similique argumentum in, porro putent consetetur vix ut. Tibique percipitur ex vim, vim id
          idque soleat tibique, has te erant doctus complectitur. Nusquam oportere vituperata id cum, adipisci persecuti an
          pro. Eu vim facer graecis, id nec dicta integre interpretaris</p>

        <div class="tile-button-container">
          <a href="http://www.google.com" class="text-decoration__none rounded__thick corporateGreen white__hover background-corporateGreen__hover border border-width__2 font-size__6 padding-topbottom__1 padding-leftright__4 margin-bottom__4 position-float__left" target="_blank">
            <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
            Learn More
          </a>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>




  </div>
  <div class="info-block-tile-row">
    <div class="info-block-tile-cell">
      <div class="info-block-tile">

        <h6 class="margin-top__0 margin-bottom__2 fiord font-weight-sourcesans__bold">Offering 1</h6>
        <p class="margin-top__0 margin-bottom__10 fiord font-weight-sourcesans__normal font-size__7">Lorem ipsum dolor sit
          amet
          pro. Eu vim facer graecis, id nec dicta integre interpretaris</p>

        <div class="tile-button-container">
          <a href="http://www.google.com" class="text-decoration__none rounded__thick corporateGreen white__hover background-corporateGreen__hover border border-width__2 font-size__6 padding-topbottom__1 padding-leftright__4 margin-bottom__4 position-float__left" target="_blank">
            <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
            Learn More
          </a>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>




    <div class="info-block-tile-cell">
      <div class="info-block-tile">

        <h6 class="margin-top__0 margin-bottom__2 fiord font-weight-sourcesans__bold">Offering 1</h6>
        <p class="margin-top__0 margin-bottom__10 fiord font-weight-sourcesans__normal font-size__7">Lorem ipsum dolor sit
          amet, ius fastidii similique argumentum in, porro putent consetetur vix ut. Tibique percipitur ex vim, vim id
          idque soleat tibique, has te erant doctus complectitur. Nusquam oportere vituperata id cum, adipisci persecuti an
          pro. Eu vim facer graecis, id nec dicta integre interpretaris</p>

        <div class="tile-button-container">
          <a href="http://www.google.com" class="text-decoration__none rounded__thick corporateGreen white__hover background-corporateGreen__hover border border-width__2 font-size__6 padding-topbottom__1 padding-leftright__4 margin-bottom__4 position-float__left" target="_blank">
            <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
            Learn More
          </a>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>




  </div>
</div>
```

And the style:

```
.info-block-tile-table{
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 2rem;
}

.info-block-tile-row{
  display: table-row;
}

.info-block-tile-cell{
  width: 25%;
  display: table-cell;
  float: none;
  border-top: 5px solid #69be28;
  border-right: 1px solid #dfe1e4;
  border-left: 1px solid #dfe1e4;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dfe1e4;
  position: relative;

}

.info-block-tile-cell .tile-button{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
}

.tile-button-container{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

.tile-button-container > a{
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-left: 1rem;
  padding-right: 1rem;
  color: #69be28;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  padding-top: 0.25rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.25rem;
  float: left;
}

.margin-bottom__4 {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}


.margin-bottom__10 {
  margin-bottom: 2.25rem;
}

.info-block-tile {
  padding: 1rem;
}
```